# Flattening an array recursively (withoout looping) javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm practicing recursion and am trying to flatten an array without looping (recursion only).  As a first step I did the iterative approach and it worked, but am stuck on the pure recursion version:

```
function flattenRecursive(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr;
    }

    return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr = arr.concat(flattenRecursive(arr)) : flattenRecursive(arr.slice(1))
}

console.log(flattenRecursive([
    [2, 7],
    [8, 3],
    [1, 4], 7
])) //should return [2,7,8,3,1,4,7] but isn't - maximum call stack error


//working version (thanks @Dave!):

function flattenRecursive(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        return arr;
    }

    return arr[0].concat(Array.isArray(arr) ? flattenRecursive(arr.slice(1)) : arr);
}

console.log(flattenRecursive([
    [2, 7],
    [8, 3],
    [1, 4], 7
]))

//returns [ 2, 7, 8, 3, 1, 4, 7 ]
```

Comment: Hint: `Array.isArray(arr)` will always be true

Comment: `arr.concat(flattenRecursive(arr))` is causing the infinite recursion.

Comment: @charlietfl - it's true the first time you call the function, which then calls the function again with the same argument - `arr` - and hence will always be true. It never gets to the last item in the array.

Comment: Just curious why you want to do this recursively. It's trivial to do it if you don't want to do it in-place. Is this a thought exercise?

Comment: @torazaburo an exercise in solidfying my understanding of recursion (academic) :) how would you do this in place?

Comment: See closely related question with in-place recursive solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491404/javascript-flatten-multidimensional-array-in-place-using-recursion/32518424#32518424. Another question which has a recursive answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158723/javascipt-flattening-an-array-of-arrays-of-objects/29158887#29158887. By the way, do you expect the solution to work on nested arrays? Your accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version that's slightly less verbose.

```js
//using reduce
function flattenRecursive(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(result, a){
    return result.concat(Array.isArray(a) ? flattenRecursive(a) : a);
  }, []);
}

//without reduce
function flattenRecursive2(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return arr;

  var head = arr.shift();
  if (Array.isArray(head))
    return flattenRecursive2(head).concat(flattenRecursive2(arr));
  else
    return [head].concat(flattenRecursive2(arr));
}

var testArray = [1,[2, 3],[[4, 5, [6, 7]], [8, 9]], 10];
console.log(flattenRecursive(testArray));
console.log(flattenRecursive2(testArray));
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey @dave that's awesome, but internally reduce uses each, which is essentially a for loop. I was messing around based on the solution you provided, and sometimes sh$t just works! updating my code above to the working solution, thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @devdropper87 - your recursive function fails if the first element in the array is not an array - e.g. `console.log(flattenRecursive([7,
    [2, 7],
    [8, 3],
    [1, 4], 7
]))`

Comment: I'm stumped, I tried to do an else if it's not an array but that's not working. what would you suggest? @dave any tips?

Comment: @devdropper87 I added an alternative that doesn't use `.reduce()`

Comment: @torazaburo the second example is now fixed for all nested array cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I do not have the reputation to comment. Here are my 2 cents.

1) be careful about your initial condition. Here, it seems that if your input is ̀`arr = [[1,2]]`, your function returns `[[1,2]]`, while you would like it to return `[1,2]`.

2) in the core of the recursion, you must be sure than you recursively call your function with a `smaller argument. Here, you should concat the first element of your array with the flattened rest of the array. The function`slice` may be handy for that.

3) It would be also be possible to use a reduce-like function.