# JS array concatenation for results of recursive flattening

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, concatenation, flatten

Good day!

Task would be to get a flat version of an array, that may include some amount of nested arrays as well as other elements. For input `[1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]` output `[1, 2, 3, 4]` expected.
*FreeCodeCamp spoiler alert.*
Naturally, recursive solution comes to mind, e.g.:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      //part of interest
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i])){
        var nestedElements = steamrollArray(arr[i]);
        for(var j = 0; j < nestedElements.length; j ++){
          result.push(nestedElements[j]);
        }
      //</part of interest>.
      } else {
        console.log("pushing: " + arr[i]);
        result.push(arr[i]);
      }
  }
  return result;
}
```

And it does it's thing. Result of sample run would be:

```
pushing: 1
pushing: 2
pushing: 3
pushing: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And the question is: what goes awry, when we use concat to add `nestedElements` (that supposedly store return result of recursive call). If we are to change first `if{}` block in `for` loop (marked as part of interest) with snippet below:

```
if (Array.isArray(arr[i])){
    var nestedElements = steamrollArray(arr[i]);
    result.concat(nestedElements);
} else {
```

we will observe the following result:

```
pushing: 1
pushing: 2
pushing: 3
pushing: 4
[1]
```

My understanding was to pass the result of each recursive call to the `concat` function, which will add the returned array to the result, but for some reason it's not the case.
Questions on this task was asked, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582352/flatten-nested-arrays-using-recursion-in-javascript), but those concerned with the flattening algorithm part, which is not questioned here.
I still fail to see the answer what exactly causes the difference. It very well might be something I simply overlooked in a hassle or as a result of my limited experience. Sorry if that's the case.

Comment: Array.concat will create a new array and append the elements to it and the result is a brand new array. Array.concat is immutable, Array.push is mutable. You might have to store the result of concat operation to nestedElements again.

Comment: My lesson here I guess is to double check specification of tools I use, especially when it is so obvious that exact line of code causes the unexpected behaviour.
Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a new array with the result.

> The **`concat()`** method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

So you need to assign the result:

```
result = result.concat(nestedElements);
// ^^^^^^ assignment
```

Answer (score 3):

I am puzzled by the accepted answer as it can only concat two arrays. What you want for a nested array is actually:

```
var flatArray = [].concat.apply([], yourNestedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my function.

```
   function _recursive_array_flat( ...args )
   {
       var _ret_array = [];
       for( _arg of args )
       {
           if ( _arg instanceof Array )
           {
               if ( _arg.length > 0 ) // work with consistent elements only
               _ret_array = _ret_array.concat( _recursive_array_flat( ..._arg ) );
           }
           else _ret_array.push( _arg );
       }

       return _ret_array;
    }

    var _ret = _recursive_array_flat( [0], 1,2,3, [ 4,5,6, [ 7,8,9 ] ] );
    console.log( _ret );
```